# telnet catch ctrl+c server

Tags: telnet, socketserver, sigint

I have written a socket-server like [here](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm). If I type `ctrl+c` in telnet, the server don't do anything now. I want to catch it like `signal(SIGINT,SIG_IGN)`
 
How can I do?

Answer (score 2):

The telnet program catches the CTRL-C character and sends it as a single byte (`\x03`) down the TCP connection to the other side.  It's up to the receiving program to decide what to do with that byte.

In the case of it being received by a "telnet daemon" intending to provide console-like interactivity via a pseudo-terminal, *that* combination generates a SIGINT to the process running under it, usually a shell.

So, to answer your question, you can either process the received `\x03` character and internally generate a SIGINT or you can run your entire program as a process spawned and controlled by telnetd under a pseudo-terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The telnet client (the process that recieves the SIGINT) should process it: either handle it locally (eg: terminate, or re-issue a prompt), or send it to the server as IAC *something* (BRK?) and/or out-of band data. 
If you want to pass the interrupt to the server, Google for "telnet IAC" will probably get you started.